# Android RxJava - GroupBy and Merge back?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

How can I order a list of Objects by its date by the following criteria:

1) all objects with date >= today

2) all objects with date < today

**Example:**

Today = 7/Feb

> List = [{5/Feb, 8/Feb, 6/Feb, 4/Feb, 9/Feb}]
>
> Expected Result =[{ 8/Feb, 9/Feb, 6/Feb, 5/Feb, 4/Feb]}

What do I have ate the moment:

```
dummyProvider
            .getAllObjects()
            .map(mapper::mapToDateObject) //Convert to new object -> DateObject
            .groupBy(dateObject -> dateObject.getDateTime().isAfterNow())
            //What now?
```

At this moment I did group them by the date (after 'now', and before 'now'), now I need to merge it back and return a `Single<List<DateObject>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion solution with `groupBy` will be overcomplicated for your case. You can do it simply without `groupBy`:

```
dummyProvider
    .getAllObjects()
    .map(mapper::mapToDateObject)
    .toList()
    .flatMapObservable(list -> 
        //emit dateObjects afterNow first
        Observable.fromIterable(list)
            .filter(dateObject -> dateObject.getDateTime().isAfterNow())
            //you did't mention this in your criteria, but according
            //to expected result I assume that you need sorted items on each side
            .sorted(...)
            //then emit dateObjects != afterNow
            .concatWith(
                Observable.fromIterable(list)
                    .filter(dateObject -> !dateObject.getDateTime().isAfterNow())
                    .sorted(...)))
    .toList()
    .subscribe(...)
```

*But* in **Kotlin** solution using `groupBy` is more elegant:

```
dummyProvider
    .getAllObjects()
    .map(mapper::mapToDateObject)
    .groupBy { it.getDateTime().isAfterNow() }
    .toList()
    .flatMapObservable { list ->
        list.first { it.key }.sorted { ... }
             .concatWith(list.first { !it.key }.sorted { ... }) }
    .toList()
```

Comment: I have the following error on both filter functions: "No instance of type variable R exists so that Observable <R> conforms to Single<List<DateObject>>". Any idea?

Comment: Yep! That worked. As you said, i had still sort my lists. Thanks.